# Systemd playing sound (service Linux)

Tags: systemd, audio, xubuntu, systemd-journald

I have this service, running on Xubuntu.

```
[Unit]
Description= Controller
After=graphical.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/controller
StandardInput=tty-force
StandardOutput=journal
Restart=always
TimeoutSec=2s

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

When a certain action happens in the program (controller), it must execute an audio (.mp3).
I can guarantee that the application works.

Now running on the service, all other program functionality works, but does not play mp3 audio.
I've tried different ways to create the service, but it does not work.

How can I make the controller program, run an audio, using a Linux service?

Comment: Does not work:

User=<yourusername>
Environment=DISPLAY=:0